# how to use regexp to replace "t e x t" by "text"?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to replace all strings like : "i love r u b y regexp" by "i love ruby regexp"

(ie grouping single letters into a word)

How would you do that?

Comment: Can you explain more formally what you need? E.g. do you need to merge just "r u b y" or all words split like that? What have you tried and what is the problem with your code?

Comment: One crude heuristic that works on your example string is to replace all consecutive occurrences of single letters by a word consisting of those letters. I'll leave it to someone else to express that in Ruby.

Comment: yeah, we need more specifics like do you know what words you need to look for? Or do you want a generic thing that will look for words that are blown up with spaces. If so that's going to be really, really hard since you'll need to do some kind of dictionary search. For instance how whould you know if an "a" is in the middle of a word or if it's an indefinite article?

Comment: my problem is generic : given a sentence how to group single letters into a word

Comment: Note that the solution has to group single letters which have following single letters - or you'll have a problem like "ilove ruby regexp" (First I is a single letter as well...)

Comment: You are right rusw1. (It is always complicated to specify functionality correctly!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
/(\b\w\b)\s+(?=\b\w\b)/\1/g
```

(I don't do Ruby, but this probably translates to:

```
"i love r u b y regexp".gsub(/(\b\w\b)\s+(?=\b\w\b)/, "\\1")
```

Online version: http://rubular.com/r/5e1jTl7MiV

If you only want to remove a single space after a single letter, then the following may be what you want:

```
(/\b\w\b\s)(?=(?:\s+|\b\w\b))/
```

Comment: Right! This should have been `\s+`. Or `\s` if you only want to remove single spaces; but then you won't remove the space after a single letter if followed by move spaces, unless you do `(\b\w\b\s)(?=(?:\s+|\b\w\b))`.

Comment: That's not really a solution. For instance if the line is `If you have an a i t won't work` or `Also I d o not like the answer` it won't work.

Comment: @Mike - you are quick to downvote answers, aren't you? It's a solution to the OP's problem. Short of using an English dictionary, of course one cannot distinguish one-letter words, such as 'a' or 'I'. It's certainly not possible using a regex. The original question doesn't mention any specific language.

Comment: Except I didn't down vote it. You're quick to blame people for down votes. I wonder if you're as quick to apologize...